# Each class has two classfiles in jar file

Tags: java, build, jar

I have a jar file which has two class files per java file.

Java:

```
Foo.java
Bar.java
```

Classfile:

```
Foo.class
Foo.class
Bar.class
Bar.class
```

I have verified that there is only one java files per class. The java files do not any contain inner classes.
I am using the ant jar-task to create the jar file. Before I execute the task, there is only one class file per class in the build directory.

I see the double class files with jar -tf jarfile.jar or when I view it in a zip program. When I unpack the files, the zip program asks if it should overwrite the existing file.

How can this happen?

Comment: Maybe you have compiled the source two times?

Comment: What happens when you extract the jar?

Comment: How does the `Foo.java` look?

Comment: Any information on the build process you're using?

Comment: How are you creating the jar?

Comment: Added info above. Just using the standard ant jar task.

Comment: I see the double class files with jar -tf jarfile.jar or when I view it in a zip program. When I unpack the files, the zip program asks if it should overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem. This is the jar task:

```
    <jar basedir="${build.class.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${subproject}.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.class.dir}" />
    </jar>
```

As I read in the Ant website

> This task forms an **implicit** FileSet and supports most attributes of  (dir becomes >basedir) as well as the nested ,  and  elements.

So it would seem that either the  tag or basedir is uneccessary. At least it works.fine if I comment out the fileset tag.

Thanks for your help and pointers!

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the Ant Jar task? If so then you can most definitely get duplicate files in the same jar file. The **duplicate** attribute is used to stop that.

> Please note that the zip format allows multiple files of the same fully-qualified name to exist
>   within a single archive. This has been documented as causing various problems for unsuspecting
>   users. If you wish to avoid this behavior you must set the duplicate attribute to a value other
>   than its default, "add".

From the Ant Manual Page: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

Comment: I was able to localize the problem with duplicate="fail". I am aware that I could use duplicate="preserve", but I am more interested in how this situation could occur.

Comment: I came across the issue by having the same files from different locations (created during a build) being added to the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I found out that just removing the fileset tag (a child tag of the jar tag) will make the final jar file not have 2 duplicate classes.
As shown in the picture, just remove the fileset tag in the pink block.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmAJY.png)