# Two files with the same name in one jar

Tags: java, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Each class has two classfiles in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122955/each-class-has-two-classfiles-in-jar-file)

Hello I have one jar with tho files witch share the same filename:

```
    /ro/sv/base/Monkey.png
```

Can somebody explain what is happening?

I have the jar here:  [DELETED]

Comment: How was the jar created?

Comment: If you use the java.util.zip API to "manually" build a JAR you can put any combo of files you want in it.  And likely some zip tools will allow you to add another member with a name identical to an existing one.

Comment: It looks like the paths are actually different: `ro/sv/base/Monkey.png` and `/ro/sv/base/Monkey.png`. One is absolute and one relative.

Comment: @Banthar - Yeah, I was just looking at it in hex and that appears to be the case, though I can't be sure because I haven't consulted the directory layout spec.  Not sure how you'd accomplish this, other than with java.util.zip, though.

Comment: this explain a lot of things! thank you very much !

Comment: aa.. guys how did you saw the differences ?

Comment: `unzip -l` gives [this output](https://gist.github.com/4637228).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Ant Jar Task documentation

> Please note that the zip format allows multiple files of the same
>   fully-qualified name to exist within a single archive. This has been
>   documented as causing various problems for unsuspecting users. If you
>   wish to avoid this behavior you must set the duplicate attribute to a
>   value other than its default, "add".

In short, you can have multiple files with the same fully qualified name in a .zip file, this is just how it works, don't add the second .png if you don't want to have this behavior.